# Unable to add model in sequelize-typescript

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to add a model with sequelize-typescript:

```
type AppMetaDataAttributes = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  version: string;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
};

type AppMetaDataCreationAttributes = Optional<AppMetaDataAttributes, 'id'>;

@Table
class AppMetaData extends Model<AppMetaDataAttributes, AppMetaDataCreationAttributes> {
  @Column
  id: string;

  @Column
  name: string;

  @Column
  version: string;

  @Column({ field: 'created_at' })
  createdAt: string;

  @Column({ field: 'updated_at' })
  updatedAt: string;

  constructor(id: string, name: string, version: string, createdAt: string, updated: string) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.version = version;
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
    this.updatedAt = updated;
  }
}
MySqlInstance.addModels([AppMetaData]);

export default AppMetaData;
```

But it is giving me this error in the line `MySqlInstance.addModels([AppMetaData]);`:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type 'typeof AppMetaData' is not assignable to type 'string | ModelCtor<Model<any, any>>'.
      Type 'typeof AppMetaData' is not assignable to type 'ModelCtor<Model<any, any>>'.
        Type 'typeof AppMetaData' is not assignable to type 'new () => Model<any, any>'.
          Types of construct signatures are incompatible.
            Type 'new (id: string, name: string, version: string, createdAt: string, updated: string) => AppMetaData' is not assignable to type 'new () => Model<any, any>'.ts(2769)
sequelize.d.ts(16, 5): The last overload is declared here.
```

I am only following the documentation provided in the official doc [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-typescript#model-definition) but not sure what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `constructor` of the `AppMetaData` model class is unnecessary.

Working example:

```
import { Optional } from 'sequelize';
import { Column, Model, Table, Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  database: 'some_db',
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  username: 'root',
  password: '',
  storage: ':memory:',
  models: [__dirname + '/models'],
});

type AppMetaDataAttributes = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  version: string;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
};

type AppMetaDataCreationAttributes = Optional<AppMetaDataAttributes, 'id'>;

@Table
class AppMetaData extends Model<
  AppMetaDataAttributes,
  AppMetaDataCreationAttributes
> {
  @Column
  id: string;

  @Column
  name: string;

  @Column
  version: string;

  @Column({ field: 'created_at' })
  createdAt: string;

  @Column({ field: 'updated_at' })
  updatedAt: string;
}
sequelize.addModels([AppMetaData]);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-2q6bnw?file=index.ts)